# Google Sheets QUERY to return if contains multiple selection and all other values

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have a data set similar to the image in cells A5:D31. I am trying to write a QUERY function that will return the records that match the "filters" in range A2:D3.

In this example, the query will return the rows highlighted in green WHERE Department = Furniture OR Electronics AND Size = Small. The other columns 'Color' and 'Store' are not specified so any value will return if the cell is not blank.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is basically an exercise in building your query text string.  For simplicity, the solution puts parentheses around text that doesn't actually need it.

For example, it returns

```
"Where (B = 'Furniture' OR B = 'Electronics') AND (C = 'Small')"
```

instead of

```
"Where (B = 'Furniture' OR B = 'Electronics') AND C = 'Small'"
```

## Formula

```
=LET(
   range,A5:D, dp,{B2;"B"}, sz,{D2;"C"}, cl,{B3;"A"}, 
   st,{D3;"D"}, nums,"D",
   querytxt,BYCOL({dp,sz,cl,st}, LAMBDA(x, LET(
     v,INDEX(x,1), c,INDEX(x,2), q,IF(ISERR(FIND(c,nums)),"'",), 
     IF(OR(v="All", LEN(TRIM(v))=0),, "("& 
       JOIN(" OR ", ARRAYFORMULA(c& " = "& q& 
       TRIM(SPLIT(v, ","))& q))& ")")))),
   QUERY(range, IF(LEN(JOIN(,querytxt)), 
     "Where "& JOIN(" AND ",TOCOL(querytxt, 1)),),1))
```

## Explanation

1. LET is used to store values and calculations for later use.
2. The initial variables define

   1. `range` of your data including headings
   2. `dp`, `sz`, `cl`, and `st` are two-row arrays that each store a reference to filter values for a column (in row 1) and the actual column they should be applied to (in row 2).

      - For example, `dp` contains `B2` in row 1, which is a reference to a cell containing filter value(s), and `"B"` in row 2 which is the column in `range` that those filter values should be applied to.
      - the labels follow the naming of your headings `dp=department`, `st=store` etc. but that is largely irrelevant and the arrays can be swapped between variables without causing issues.
   3. Lastly `nums` is a string that identifies columns that contain numbers rather than strings.  In this case only column D.  If the Size column C also contained numbers, then you'd add `C` to that string.  For example `nums,"CD",` or `nums,"DC",`.  If you have columns higher than `Z` then the approach needs to be tweaked.
3. `querytxt` stores an array of values.  Each value represents the filter string for one column or is empty.  The array is created as follows:

   1. BYCOL is used to pass each of the filter variables into a LAMBDA function one-by-one, and the LAMBDA stores the current column in the variable `x`.
   2. The LAMDA's formula uses another LET function to create three additional variables:

      1. `v` stores the first row of `x` (the filter values)
      2. `c` stores the second row of `x` (the column letter)
      3. `q` stores nothing if `c` is in `nums`, otherwise it stores a single quote `'`. `q` is used to ensure proper syntax for number vs. text columns.
   3. The formula next checks if `v="All"` or no value, since filtering by everything is equivalent to filtering by nothing, and returns nothing further if TRUE.

      - LEN is used to test for characters in `v` after first applying TRIM so that a cell containing only spaces is treated as empty.
   4. If there is a string in `v` that isn't `"All"`, then the formula creates a string made up of:

      1. An array of values is created within an ARRAYFORMULA by:

         1. Splitting `v` on `,` with TRIM removing any spaces padding the values: `TRIM(SPLIT(v, ","))`
         2. Each value in the array from SPLIT has `c` & `" = "` & `q` prepended, and `q` appended.  For example if `v="Furniture, Electronics"` and `c="B"` and `q="'"` then the result would be:

            ```
            {"B = 'Furniture'", "B = 'Electronics'"}
            ```
      2. The array of values is joined with `" OR "` then placed within parenthesis `()`  and that is the string returned for the current `x`.

         - For example, using the previous example where `x={B2;"B"}={"Furniture, Electronics","B"}`, therefore `v="Furniture, Electronics"`, `c="B"` and `q="'"` the formula would return the following for `x`:

           ```
           "(B = 'Furniture' OR B = 'Electronics')"
           ```
4. Finally the QUERY function is created using the values from `querytxt`.  Using the example values, it would return the result of:

   ```
   =QUERY(range, "Where (B = 'Furniture' OR B = 'Electronics') AND (C = 'Small')",1)
   ```

   This is achieved by:

   1. IF is used to return an empty value if `querytxt` contains no filters (equivalent to all column filters set to `"All"` or blank).
   2. If there are filters then TOCOL is used to remove any empty values and then  `querytxt` is joined using `" AND "` and `"Where "` is prepended.

[image: Complete sheet showing source data, results and formula]

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach using *matches* rather than booleans to handle multiple *wheres* per column (as we can concatenate the terms with |):

```
=arrayformula(let(
cols,{"A";"B";"C";"D"},
filtcells,{"B3";"B2";"D2";"D3"},
regex_,lambda(x,if(x="all","'.*'","'"&join("|",trim(split(x,",")))&"'")),
string,"where "&join(" and ",map(cols,filtcells,lambda(eachcol,eachcell,eachcol&" matches "&regex_(indirect(eachcell))))),
query(A5:D,string,1)))
```

N.B. when the relevant filter cell is set to 'all', a '.*' regex is used (i.e. any number of any character) to return all rows.